# Computing the sides of inscribed polygons

Tags: geometry

For regular polygons inscribed in a circle of radius $1$, use $S(6)=1$ to conclude that:

$$S(12) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$$

$$S(24) = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}$$

Comment: if anyone could add formatting I would appreciate it I am new to the formatting here.

Comment: I edited your post and added $\LaTeX$ markup. Check [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/4583) to learn how to do it yourself next time.

Answer (score 1):

For a hexagon, each of the six triangles that define the inscribed polygon is an equilateral triangle.  Thus, the radius of the circle is $1$, and the angle subtended is $\pi/3$.  To double the number of sides, we half the angle, and use

$$S(12) = 2 \sin{\frac{\pi}{12}} = 2 \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos{(\pi/6)}}{2}} = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}$$

For $24$ sides, half again:

$$S(12) = 2 \sin{\frac{\pi}{24}} = 2 \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos{(\pi/12)}}{2}} = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}$$

Comment: make sense thank you.  I was given 3 equations by my teacher in solving this problem.  I prefer to do it the way you showed me and I did it that way first.  But what she told me to do is use the pythagorean thm.  In dividing the polygon into triangles she gave me (using variables x, and a, as the components of the radius and a side of the triangle and variable s as the side of the polygon.  She gave me: x+a=1, x^2+(1/2)^2=s^2, and a^2 + (1/2)^2 = 1^2.  She said this could be used to solve the value S(12) and then for S(24) etc....